# Unable to call Application Event from VF Page

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, cometd

In the VF page myExternalEvent is undefined so, code throws exception. Following code was working fine before winter 17.

```
$Lightning.use(
    "nm:myApplication",
    function () {
        $Lightning.createComponent(
            "nm:myComponent", {
                label: "Press Me!",
                "objectId": recordId
            },
            "lightning",
            function (cmp) {
                // Connect to the CometD endpoint  
                $.cometd.init({
                    url: window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + '/cometd/24.0/',
                    requestHeaders: {
                        Authorization: 'OAuth {!$Api.Session_ID}'
                    }
                });

                // Subscribe to a topic. JSON-encoded update will be returned in the callback  
                // In this example we are using this only to track the generated event  
                $.cometd.subscribe('/topic/myTopic', function (message) {
                    //You can use message as it will return you many attributes  
                    //I am just using to track that event is generated
                    if (message.data.sobject.nm__Contact__c && !(message.data.sobject.nm__Contact__c != "{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}" &&
                            message.data.sobject.nm__Contact__c.slice(0, 15) != "{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}")) {
                        var myExternalEvent = $A.get("e.nm:ConversationReload");
                        //myExternalEvent is undefined. So, following line is throwing exception.
                        myExternalEvent.setParams({
                            recordId: message.data.sobject.nm__Contact__c
                        });
                        myExternalEvent.fire();
                    }
                });
            })
    });
```

However, if I am exposing a method as API -

```
<aura:method name="refresh" action="
{!c.refresh}
"
description="Sample method with parameters">
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />
</aura:method>
```

then in controller -

```
refresh : function(component, event, helper) {
var params = event.getParam('arguments');
if (params)
{ // check if recordId is same as objectId // fire application event or reload conversation }
}
```

PS: I don't want to expose method as API is there any other way?
Can I use cometd in lightning? If not then is there any alternative to cometd which will work in lightning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out that ConversationReload Event doesn't have access="global" and VF Page from where I was trying to access event was not part of the package.

Answer (score 0):

@Saurabh Mishara Did you register "ConversationReload" event in component? It would be good if you post your component code here.

Comment: I have registered event in myComponent <aura:registerEvent name="ConversationReload" type="c:ConversationReload"/> which also handles event <aura:handler event="c:ConversationReload" action="{!c.reloadConversation}"/> but still event object in VF page is undefined.

Comment: I have tested this code in some other org without using steaming API. So, It is working without even registering event.